# Date manipulations in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using a dropdownlist and a calendar control in my page. In that I am having following list items.
1)Last Week
2)last month

If I choose last week in the dropdownlist the calendar control should display the date range from date 7 days ago and today's date. 
How can I get it through Java Script

Answer (score 11):

```
// current date
var now = new Date();
// 7 days earlier
now.setDate(now.getDate()-7);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var curDate = new Date();
var prevDate = new Date();

prevDate.setDate ( curDate.getDate() - 7 );
```

Comment: Hi It shows the difference of date only. For example Today's date is 1. This function gives the output as -6.

but the need is 26/01/2010 to 01/02/2010

Comment: if (sValue == "lastweek") {
var cdate = new Date();
var dateString = cdate.getMonth() + "/" + cdate.getDate() + "/" + cdate.getFullYear() + " "

var pdate = cdate.setDate(cdate.getDate() - 7);

alert(pdate);
radTRStart.set_SelectedDate = pdate.format("mm/dd/yyyy");


Use this script function any dropdown selected change event. You will come to know the difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [DateJS](http://datejs.com) library?

Its return

- 7 days ago => Monday, January 25, 2010 12:00:00 AM
- last week => Monday, January 25, 2010 12:00:00 AM
- last month => Friday, January 01, 2010 12:00:00 AM

Comment: I want this only. Can you tell me how to use this?

Comment: There is documentation page here http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation